# Powershell: 'The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters'

Tags: powershell, xcopy, file-copying, copy-item, max-path

I tried to use powershell command `copy-item` as `xcopy`to copy content of one disk to another one.

```
copy-item -Path h:\* -Destination g:\ -Recurse -Force
```

However, I encountered the following errors:

> Copy-Item : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The
>   fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
>   directory name must be less than 248 characters.

I got these errors enough to discourage manually search and copy files or folders with long paths. What is the best way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know `robocopy` deals with this automatically (at least you would have to disable support for long paths explicitly). So you could use

```
robocopy h:\ g:\ /E
```

if you're not too adverse to a native command instead of a pure PowerShell solution.

Usually you can prepend `\\?\` to a path to allow handling paths with up to 32k characters but it could well be that this might not help with .NET.

Comment: The BCL team had a series on support for long files paths some time back, which discusses the "\\?\" option: [Long Paths in .NET, Part 1 of 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

On Codeplex Microsoft hosts an [***experimental*** long path wrapper](http://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Long%20Path&referringTitle=Home) which provides functionality to make it easier to work with paths that are longer than the current 259 character limit of the System.IO namespace.

An example of how to copy a file using this wrapper in Powershell:

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadfile("C:\Users\stackoverflow\Desktop\Microsoft.Experimental.IO.dll")
[microsoft.experimental.io.longpathfile]::Copy((gi .\myversion.txt).fullname, "C:\users\stackoverflow\desktop\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",$true)
```

Other samples can be found [here](http://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Long%20Path%20Samples&referringTitle=Long%20Path).