# Recursively copy folders with long file names (more than 260 chars)

Tags: powershell, xcopy, max-path

I am trying to automate copy/replication of drives. Many of the drives have long file names, that fail the process midway.

I was using this copy command, but both these fail.

```
XCOPY /E c:\folder-you-want-to-copy\*.* C:\destinationfolder\ 

copy-item -Path K:\* -Destination E:\ -Recurse -Force
```

> Copy-Item : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 260 characters.

I then tried SO help [power shell from here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10224545/6085193) and [SO help here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40453635/6085193), but the enable option was missing in Win 10 policy for my machine

How can I recursively copy the files from one drive to another drive with the long file names/path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Powershell 5.1 there is a Registry setting that can be used to handle Long Paths within a Powershell script.
Run the following command to check if the value of **LongPathsEnabled** is set to **1**.

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem LongPathsEnabled
```

Using an Administrator Powershell, execute the following command.

```
Set-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem' -Name 'LongPathsEnabled' -value 1
```

This will allow the Copy-Item (and other *-Item commands) to avoid the 256 char limit, without having to modify the script.

I added the following code to my script to check if this value is set, in case we move to a new build machine.

```
$LongPath = Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" LongPathsEnabled
if ($LongPath.LongPathsEnabled -ne 1) {
    Write-Host "LongPathsEnabled is not set. Build paths are likely to exceed 256 characters and will fail."
    Exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`robocopy` does not adhere to the 260 character limit (unless you usie the /256 switch):

```
robocopy K:\ E:\ /E
```

`/E` is to Copy Subfolders, including Empty Subfolders, if you don't want empty folders copied use `/S` instead.

[Full robocopy syntax](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

Comment: will try this and let you know, 1) do I need to install robocopy? how long would it take for 1 or 2TB over USB 3  2) its not mirroring, correct? just copy the files and structure?

Comment: robocopy is included with most modern versions of windows, can't comment on time as it depends on the number of files and their size. Yes that's a straight copy, mirroring uses a different switch (check syntax if you wanted this)

Comment: If it crashes, is there a continue from the current place option, and can it do a parallel copy to speed things up.

Comment: @Transformer robocopy doesn't have a resume option per-se, but it skips over files that have not changed so you can re-run pretty quickly. For multi-threaded take a look at the [/MT switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)... if it's crashing regularly you've probably got a very dodgy file as it's a really solid program!